# Javascript/PHP: Getting Updated Data from an Updated File

Tags: php, javascript

When my page first opens, a function containing this code is called, and it works just as expected. In the background, `displaydata.txt` is being updated every 500ms (opened with PHP's `fopen(..., "w")` and completely rewritten). When the function containing this code is called again (from `setInterval(...)` ), the page does not update with the new data in `displaydata.txt` and the old data from when the page was first loaded is used.

The data file is successfully being updated. When the page is refreshed, the new data is displayed.

````
var interval2=setInterval(function(){readData()},500); //Updates table data every half second

function readData() {
//Read data from a text file into a php array
<?php
$fileName = "/var/www/displaydata.txt";
$phpArray = file_get_contents($fileName); //Read entire file into string        
$phpArray = explode("```",$phpArray); //Break up the array into pieces divided by "```"
$tempArray = json_encode($phpArray); //Prepare the php array to be converted to javascript
echo "var jsArray = " . $tempArray . ";\n";  //Convert to javascript array
?>


//Fill table based on text file.
for (var i = 0; i < (jsArray.length - 1); i+=2) 
{
    document.getElementById( jsArray[i] ).value = jsArray[(i + 1)]; 
}

}
````

Comment: Are you calling a PHP function from a Javascript code (setInterval) ? It cannot work just as simply. PHP executes on the server, and JS on the client. Could you give your Javascript code including the setInterval call ?

Comment: I've updated my code. PHP code is being called from within a javascript function.

Comment: You cannot call readData from a Javascript code, because it is not a Javascript function. If you need such a behavior, learn about AJAX (cf user1759572's answer below).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX to fetch data from server. 
If you are using JQuery javascript library check [JQuery ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)

Comment: ... and if your not, W3Schools' tutorial explains Ajax without jQuery (native Javascript) : www.w3schools.com/ajax/